# Compare two colums in awk

Tags: awk

I'm trying to match the first column in two tables. In below example, I need to get expiry date on the second table and output it using `AWK.

i tried below code but its not working

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next;}{print $0 "," ($1 in a ? a[$1] : $2 )}' table1 table2
```

Table1

```
LICENSE,ALLOCATION,IN_USE
LicenseA,1102,98
LicenseB,267,105
LicenseC,546,500
LicenseD,982,23
```

Table2

```
LICENSE,EXPIRY
LicenseA,03/31/2019
LicenseB,03/25/2019
LicenseC,03/31/2019
```

Desired output:

```
LICENSE,ALLOCATION,IN_USE,EXPIRY
LicenseA,1102,98,03/31/2019
LicenseB,267,105,03/25/2019
LicenseC,546,500,03/31/2019
LicenseD,982,23,N/A
```

Comment: Since the desired output is basically table1 with the column from table2 appended to each line, you need to read table2 first to build your lookup table, and then read table1.  In other words, you're reading the files in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very similar approach to Johns well explained answer but using filenames for pattern matching instead of detecting file by line numbers and next.

`awk -F, 'FILENAME == "table1" {arr[$1] = $0}; FILENAME == "table2" {print arr[$1],$2}' OFS=, table1 table2`

Comment: Hi, there is one problem, the command is deleting the line if doesn't find expiry in table2, how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next;}{print $0,a[$1]?a[$1]:"N/A"}' OFS=, Table2 Table1
LICENSE,ALLOCATION,IN_USE,EXPIRY
LicenseA,1102,98,03/31/2019
LicenseB,267,105,03/25/2019
LicenseC,546,500,03/31/2019
LicenseD,982,23,N/A
```

### Answer for original question

Try:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next;}{print a[$1],$2}' OFS=, table1 table2
LICENSE,ALLOCATION,IN_USE,EXPIRY
LicenseA,1102,98,03/31/2019
LicenseB,267,105,03/25/2019
LicenseC,546,500,03/31/2019
```

#### How it works:

- `-F,`

  Set the field separator on input to a comma.
- `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next;}`

  For the first file, `table1`, collect all its data in an associative array, `a`, in which each line, `$0`, is save under the eky of its first field, `$1`.
- `print a[$1],$2`

  While reading the second file, `table2`, print the line from table`that corresponds to the first field followed by the expiry,`$2`.
- `OFS=,`

  Set the Output Field Separator to a comma.

Comment: Thanks it works!, appreciate the detailed explanation too

Comment: Hi, there is one problem, the command is deleting the line if doesn't  find expiry in table2, how to solve this?

Comment: @impitnin step 1 would be to include that case in your posted sample input/output in your question and describe there how you want it handled.

Comment: @EdMorton, Hi, updated Table1 with additional data which is LicenseD, LicenseD doesnt expire so it is not in Table2,. in the output i would like to put 'N/A' in expiry if this is not existing in Table3, thank you

Comment: @impitnin See the updated answer for handling of the missing expiry.

Answer (score 0):

If, like your example data, your files happen to have the same key values in the same order, you could use `paste` and `cut` instead:

```
njv@pandion:~$ paste -d, Table1 Table2|cut -f1,2,3,5 -d,
LICENSE,ALLOCATION,IN_USE,EXPIRY
LicenseA,1102,98,03/31/2019
LicenseB,267,105,03/25/2019
LicenseC,546,500,03/31/2019
```

- `paste` takes two or more files as arguments and prints out the concatenation of each file's first line, followed by the concatenation of each file's second line, etc.
- `-d` specifies the separator to use when concatenating. The default is `tab`.
- `cut` with the `-f` option takes columnar data as input, separated by the character specified in the `-d` option (also `tab` by default), and prints the columns specified after `-f`.